# Listbox selectionmode=Extended binding to a datatable. Need to get selected items on button click using MVVM light

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a listbox

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbFamilies" Margin="41,45,38.25,111" ToolTip="Select the tables to seed" ItemsSource="{Binding ManTntFmly.FmlyList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listBoxTemplate}" SelectionMode="Extended"/>
```

The FmlyList is a Datatable which is bound using DataBinding.

1. I need to find out all the items
   which have been selected from the
   listbox. How do I do that using the
   view model?
2. Additionally, how do I get key's to
       be passed instead of the values
       during the selection?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a post which should answer your question:[Multi Select Listbox](http://www.gbogea.com/2010/01/02/mvvm-multiselect-listbox)